# Android Transparent ActionBar for FadingActionBar

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I am using [FadingActionBar](https://github.com/ManuelPeinado/FadingActionBar) library and I realized that the sample code contains a drawable named `R.drawable.ab_background`. After looking through the folders, I realized that `ab_background` do not exist. This [article](http://cyrilmottier.com/2013/05/24/pushing-the-actionbar-to-the-next-level/) by Cyril Mottier also stated the use of `ab_background` yet did not link the file anywhere in the article.

Is the file from the original ActionBar provided by Android, or do I have to create my own? I'm using ActionBarCompact. Thank you!

Comment: [It's in the XHDPI folder](https://github.com/ManuelPeinado/FadingActionBar/blob/master/samples-actionbarcompat/res/drawable-xhdpi/ab_background.9.png)

Comment: @adneal Wow.. can't believe I'm that dumb.. thanks! :D